# Remove-WebBindings removing binding from all IIS sites

Tags: powershell, iis-10

I am creating a Powershell script using the WebAdministration module to create a couple of sites and automatically add bindings

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$config = @{
    Sites = @( 
        @{
            Name = "Site1";
            Path = "Path1";
            Bindings = @(
                @{ Protocol = "http"; Port = 80;},
                @{ Protocol = "https"; Port = 443;}
            );
        },
        @{
            Name = "Site2";
            Path = "Path2";
            Bindings = @(
                @{ Protocol = "http"; Port = 3009;}
            );
        }
    )
}

foreach($site in $config.Sites){
    $physicalPath = Get-Item "$($site.Path)"
    # Create the current site
    New-WebSite -Name "$($site.Name)" -PhysicalPath $physicalPath.FullName

    ## Trying to remove default port 80 binding for the current site
    Remove-WebBinding -Name $site.Name -Port 80 -Protocol "http"

    ## Add the desired bindings
    foreach ($binding in $site.Bindings){
        New-WebBinding -Name "$($site.Name)" -Protocol $binding.Protocol -Port $binding.Port
    }
}
```

When I do this though, I'm left without a binding on port 80 Site1. It looks like `Remove-WebBinding -Name $site.Name -Port 80 -Protocol "http"` is removing bindings for both sites.

```
PS > Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Site1            1    Started    Path1                          https *:443: sslFlags=0
Site2            2    Stopped    Path2                          http *:3009:
```

If I do this without attempting to modify any bindings

```
foreach($site in $config.Sites){
    $physicalPath = Get-Item "$($site.Path)"
    # Create the current site
    New-WebSite -Name "$($site.Name)" -PhysicalPath $physicalPath.FullName
}
```

I end up with both sites bound to port 80

```
PS > Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Site1            1    Started    Path1                          http *:80:
Site2            2    Stopped    Path2                          http *:80:
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get around `Remove-WebBinding` by using the first binding when creating the site and then iterating through any remaining bindings.

```
foreach($site in $config.Sites){
    $physicalPath = Get-Item "$($site.Path)"

    $defaultBinding = ($site.Bindings | Select-Object -First 1)

    # Use Splatting
    $newWebSiteParams = @{
        Name = $site.Name;
        PhysicalPath = $physicalPath.FullName;
        ApplicationPool = $site.ApplicationPool
        Port = $defaultBinding.Port
        SSL = $defaultBinding.Protocol -eq 'https'
    }

    # Create the current site with command splatting
    New-WebSite @newWebSiteParams

    ## Add the remaining bindings
    foreach ($binding in ($site.Bindings | Select-Object -Skip 1)){
        New-WebBinding -Name "$($site.Name)" -Protocol $binding.Protocol -Port $binding.Port
    }
}
```

Still not sure why `Remove-WebBinding` appeared to be removing the binding from both sites.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen similar behavior.  Rather than attempting to explicitly find and remove a binding entry, I have found more success using the pipeline to reference an already identified object.

For example:

```
Get-Website -Name "$($site.Name)" | Get-WebBinding -Protocol "http" -Port 80 | Remove-WebBinding
```